# Como saber se uma coluna existe numa tabela no Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Estou tentando adicionar uma nova coluna numa tabela no Oracle, e quero saber se ela já existe ou não. Tenho tentado algo assim:

```
IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
            WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'minhaTabela' 
            AND  COLUMN_NAME = 'minhaColuna')
```

Como que posso saber se uma coluna já existe numa tabela no Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Uso essa query:

 SELECT column_name AS FOUND
 FROM user_tab_cols WHERE table_name = '__TABLE_NAME__'
 and column_name = '__COLUMN_NAME__';

A query vai retorna  a coluna se ela existir;
```

Agora se você quiser criar se ela NÃO existir, o caminho é através da PL/SQL:

```
  /*Verifica se coluna já existe e se não houver insere com valor padrão 'A'*/
DECLARE 
 col_count  integer;
BEGIN 
 SELECT count(*)
   into col_count
 FROM user_tab_columns
 WHERE table_name = '<nomeTabela>'
 AND column_name = '<nomeColuna>';

 IF col_count = 0 THEN 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE nomeTabela add nomeColuna char(1) default ''A'' not null';
    COMMIT;
 END IF;
 exception when others then
 if sqlcode = -01430 || -06512 then
   null;
 end if;
END;
```

PL/SQL  retirada deste link: http://respostas.guj.com.br/38479-inserindo-coluna-na-tabela-oracle-com-condicional

Comment: A questão é que eu não sei o nome da tabela, apenas o nome da coluna, como faço? Um select All_Tables eu listo as tabelas de schema e como pego a coluna xpto em um schema? Pode ser que eu tenha várias tabelas com a mesma coluna e por isso preciso de um select que busque em todo schema

Comment: Achei isso: SELECT *
  FROM all_tab_columns
WHERE upper(column_name)  LIKE '%COLUMN_NAME%'